# Run-time settings for iOS app launch file

Tags: ios, xml, uistoryboard, xib, launch-screen

My app (a game) loads instantaneously and I would rather not have a launch screen at all. But since it seems to be mandatory for the app store I suppose I will need a launch file (for iOS 8 and later) as well as launch images (for iOS 7 and earlier).

The launch screen for my app should be a plain solid color, the same as the background color of my app. The problem is that the background color can change, so if the launch screen only displays the default color it will not match any non-default background color.

1. Is there a way to get a color from a settings file to a storyboard
   or XIB launch file so that the correct color can be displayed while
   the app is loading?
2. Is it possible to replace the launch image at run-time? If
   so, the app could edit the launch image when the background          color changes in order to prepare for the next time the app gets loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do. Nothing about a launch image or a launch screen file can be changed by the app.

I have the same problem with one of my apps. A user can change the color scheme of the app but there's no way to update the launch screen to match.

My less-than-ideal compromise is to show my launch screen in grayscale and then fade in the first screen.

I supposed another option is to do what Apple doesn't recommend but doesn't seem to mind and that is to have a "splash" screen instead of a proper launch screen. This way the splash screen is so different from the first screen of your app, a difference in color doesn't matter.